# Why we can’t to install virtual machine at iPad Pro with M1 chip?

Tags: ipad, ipados, magic-keyboard-ipad

We know the iPad use the same chip of the Mac Pro, but I don’t understand why we can’t to install the virtual machine at the iPad Pro, recently I buy this device but now I’m a little sorry kkkk

Answer (score 3):

So there are two main types of VMS: [(1) system virtual machines and (2) process virtual machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine).

System VMs utilize a hypervisor to "use native execution to share and manage hardware, allowing for multiple environments which are isolated from one another, yet exist on the same physical machine". So while the M1 chip itself is fully capable of supporting that, iPadOS isn't, so unless Apple adds support for this, these will be impossible on iPadOS. Even if you jailbreak it, it would be a considerably difficult task to accomplish since the OS was not designed with hypervisors in mind, and thus will not handle some of its resources being taken away from it well.

On the other hand, process virtual machines "are designed to execute computer programs in a platform-independent environment" and "run as a normal application inside a host OS and supports a single process". So not only can these exist on iPadOS, but they do exist on iPadOS: [ish](https://github.com/ish-app/ish) and [UTM](https://getutm.app/) are a couple that you can use (though UTM no longer works without jailbreak after iOS 13 due to Apple's sandboxing features, and no jailbreak exists for iOS 15 yet, so would have to use iOS 14 jailbroken or iOS 11 - 13.) While they both use emulation, [ish uses some tricks that allow it to be 3-5x faster than pure emulation](https://github.com/ish-app/ish#a-note-on-the-jit), though ish is just a Linux shell. UTM also uses some tricks to make it faster than pure emulation, and it supports Windows and Linux, but would also require a jailbreak for your iPad.

So unfortunately there's no fast, convenient way of using a VM on your M1 iPad (unless a Linux shell is all you need). If you need to use a desktop OS from your iPad, for the time being you'll need to connect to one remotely either through some SSH, VNC, RDP, etc. app or through the browser.